# Haproxy gateway settings - client and server are on the same subnetwork

Tags: load-balancing, iptables, haproxy, netfilter, iproute

I'm trying to setup a haproxy gateway between server and client for full transparent proxy like below diagram. My main aim is to provide load balancing.

There is a simple application that listens port 25 in the server side. The client tries to connect port 25 on the gateway machine, and haproxy on the gateway chooses an avaliable server then redirects the connection to the server.

Network analysis of this approach produces tcp flow like diagram: The client resets the connection at the end since it doesn't send a syn packet to the server.

Is this haproxy usage true and my problem related configuation? Or should the client connect to the server directly (This doesn't make much sense to me but I'm not sure actually. If this is true then how haproxy will intervene the connection and make load balancing)?

**EDIT:**

I've started to think this problem is related to routing and NAT on the gateway. All of these three machines are in same subnetwork but I've added routes to the gateway for both client and server. Also rules on the gateway are:

```
iptables -t mangle -N DIVERT
iptables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j MARK --set-mark 0x01/0x01
iptables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j ACCEPT
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m socket -j DIVERT
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 25 -j TPROXY \
         --tproxy-mark 0x1/0x1 --on-port 10025

ip route flush table 100
ip rule add fwmark 1 lookup 100
ip route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table 100
```

**Now the question is** what should I do in the gateway to change `"syn-ack (src: S, dst: C)"` to `"syn-ack (src: GW, dst: C)"`?

[image: TCP flow diagram]

Comment: Hmm... http://superuser.com/questions/942006/why-does-iptables-not-doing-dnat-for-the-same-subnet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://blog.haproxy.com/2013/09/16/howto-transparent-proxying-and-binding-with-haproxy-and-aloha-load-balancer/) is the definition of my situation.

> Here comes the transparent proxy mode: HAProxy can be configured to spoof the client IP address when establishing the TCP connection to the server. That way, the server thinks the connection comes from the client directly (of course, the server must answer back to HAProxy and not to the client, otherwise it can’t work: the client will get an acknowledge from the server IP while it has established the connection on HAProxy‘s IP).

**And the answer is** to set ip_nonlocal_bind system control.